# Python wget saves a file. how to get data in variable

Tags: python

i am using wget in python as

```
import wget
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.facebook.com/hellomeets/events"

down = wget.download(url)
print down
```

and it download the html data into a file. but i want it on variable. i am new in python. any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python)

Comment: Why are you using `wget` then? Why not use `requests`?

Comment: i want to scrap facebook pages and i read it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990597/using-beautifulsoup-to-parse-facebook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `wget` to download the HTML to a file then read it in, you can just get the HTML directly. This is using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (way better than pythons urllibs in my opinion)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.facebook.com/hellomeets/events"

html = requests.get(url).text
print html
```

This is an example using pythons built in `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.facebook.com/hellomeets/events"

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print html
```

#### Edit

I know see what you mean in the difference between HTML gotten directly from the website vs the HTML gotten from the `wget` module. Here is how you would do it using the `wget` module:

```
import wget
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.facebook.com/hellomeets/events"

down = wget.download(url)

f = open(down, 'r')
htmlText = "\n".join(f.readlines())
f.close()
print htmlText
```

Comment: i have done inspect element and i did not get the exactly text . so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990597/using-beautifulsoup-to-parse-facebook i read that we have to use wget

Comment: @Harish I see what you mean now...sorry about that my updated answer should be what you want. Also the `wget` module doesnt like having the same file twice. so make sure to always remove the `events` file before running the script, or have the script delete it before downloading it

Comment: thanks  @heinst but still when i do the scrapping it show the different data because facebook page need to be logged in for all the authorization to access data so.  pls help to sort it out. thanks again

Comment: @Harish that should be a whole new question and will require a lot more code than what you have now.